# How to lock the screen in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

Usually I develop in Java but now I need to write an app that will block the whole computer's screen every X minutes for Y minutes. It needs to make a break (I want to have a similar app in Windows like in Linux).
So I suggest I need to use C++ and User32.dll to achieve it? Am i right? (I don't want to develop an application in C#). Could anybody give me an idea which methods to use to lock the screen, I'm a newby in WinAPI developing.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "lock" the screen?  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Well I want to place timer that counts time left until the end of the break and make the whole screen unresponsive to clicks

Comment: I thought that there were plenty of apps that do this already - why write your own?

Comment: I would be very grateful if you hint me some open source application with this functional....

Comment: Related question in [.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812562/how-to-lock-windows-like-windows-l-from-net) and [VB6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911548/simulate-windowskeyl-in-visual-basic)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just link your application to `user32.dll` and call the [`LockWorkStation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockworkstation) function directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very helpful, but are there any variants to do not turn off the screen, just make it unresponsive?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. You might be able to make a popup window that steals mouse and keyboard focus and is unresponsive until the timeout occurs.

Comment: `Rundll32.exe` expects a specific [function signature](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787) which `LockWorkStation()` [does not have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875(v=vs.85).aspx). You should not mix them. I've removed this from your answer.