# How to Lock Windows (like "Windows + L") from .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

You can lock a Windows PC by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

How can I lock a Windows PC using VB.NET or C#?

A short example would be helpful.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259571/how-to-lock-the-screen-in-windows) in C/C++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call the [LockWorkStation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function using PInvoke.

Answer (score 7):

The following code can be used to Lock a Computer programmatically.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void LockWorkStation();
```

Comment: `rundll32` is not designed to invoke arbitrary exported functions.