# Create a custom lock screen Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7

I think the title is pretty self explanatory. The material available on the net is largely on setting up custom images during the lock screen time.

The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259571/how-to-lock-the-screen-in-windows) talks about invoking the windows provided lock screen by using the user32.dll.

I want to ask if there is any API that would let me use my own lock screen on Windows 7? The reason is that I have developed my own face recognition algorithm but I want to integrate it with the windows locking mechanism.

One application that actually does the same thing is [Winlockpro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winlockpro/) that creates custom lock screens for Windows 8. It uses custom forms in VB for the images and links the rest to a DLL.

Can someone guide me to some useful resources (API's etc) for this?

Answer (score 9):

You need to implement a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  There are several examples on the web, and the link above to MSDN should get you started.  (Believe it or not, it's *much* simpler than implementing a GINA provider was in XP.)